# Assigning object properties based on a ternary conditional inside a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

in the code below I'm assigning data retrieved from an API to a variable called groupedGamesListing.

With that variable, I'm selecting the data and creating a new Object called GroupedGames.

I had it working, but now I'm trying to introduce a new property called GameControllerId.

I need GameControllerId to be one of two numbers, depending on a year.

I started to write the code, but I can't figure out how to represent an if/then or Ternary Operator inside the lambda expression.

Here is what I'm working with.

```
var groupedGamesListing = apiResults.Select(games => new GroupedGames
{
   // ...
   GameId = games.Select(g => g.CurrentGameId).FirstOrDefault().ToString(),
   GameControllerId = games.Select(g => { (g.GameYear == 2018) ? 34729 : 99483  }),
   // ...
}).ToList();
```

So if the g.GameYear is 2018, then I need the GameControllerId to be 34729.  If not, then 99483.

Is this possible inside the expression above?

Thanks!

Comment: `games` is *several* games - it's not clear what value you'd want to select if one was in 2018 and one was in 2017.

Comment: Do you want to select all the games' `GameControllerId` or just 1?

Comment: @JonSkeet I see what you mean...in my other properties inside this statement, I used FirstOrDefault().  But everytime I try to add that, it tells me that FirstOrDefault() doesn't exist in the current context....

Comment: I added GameId to show what is currently working...

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell If you're interested only in the first game, why don't you select it before, and then extract the properties you need?

Comment: So you don't care if different games have different years? You're happy to just take the first? Note that It's simpler to use `GameId = games.FirstOrDefault()?.CurrentGameId?.ToString()`

Comment: And for `GameControllerId`, what do you want the result to be if there aren't any games?

Comment: @JonSkeet the query creates a list, List<GroupGames>  So different games will have different years. My query worked until I tried adding this new property. Do the question marks mean that it's nullable (?.CurrentGameId?) ?  Thanks.

Comment: You might benefit from a `apiResults.SelectMany(x => x)` and _then_ trying to go into your `Select(x => ...)` logic.  Maybe you'd benefit from condensing your list of lists into one big set of games.

Comment: `?.` is the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators). I don't know what the first part of your comment means though. I know you're creating a list, but I'm assuming that `games` is already something representing multiple games. It would really help if you'd provide the concrete data types and sample data so we don't have to guess this.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks! I never knew you could omit the .Select part like that.

Comment: I don't mean to geek out, but it's pretty cool watching a @JonSkeet chat in realtime

Comment: @codeMonkey what's @JonSkeet?  I'm sorry I'm ignorant.

Comment: He's a Sr. Software Engineer at Google and kind of a C# legend :) https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your exact use case, but you could consider

```
var groupedGamesListing = apiResults.SelectMany(g => new GroupedGames
    {
        // ...
        GameId = g.CurrentGameId.ToString(),
        GameControllerId = (g.GameYear == 2018) ? 34729 : 99483,
        // ...
    }).ToList();
```

It looks like you might be running into issues from `apiResults` being a list of lists, so this would flatten the original object.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked great!  I had to change up the statement a bit, but in the end, it is much cleaner now and works as expected.

Comment: Note that this could be simplified very easily by replacing `.SelectMany(x => x).Select(g => {` with `.SelectMany(g => {`

Comment: @JonSkeet that's an excellent point. I will update the answer.

Comment: Better. Next you can make it an expression-bodied lambda, of course: `SelectMany(g => new GroupedGames { ... })` :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I couldn't remember if conditional ternary operator would work still in that case, but considering the source I'll trust it will. :) I will further update. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I previously left a comment suggesting that this was a bad practice, but I misunderstood the code; using a `SelectMany` is fine here. However you might consider representing dates by `DateTime` objects, and might also consider putting 2018, 34729 and 99483 into constants representing their meanings.

Comment: Can't believe I got Jon Skeet and @EricLippert replying to me in one day :D Happy Friday